# Is it true that if V1 and V2 are linearly independent eigen vectors then they correspond to distinct eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not getting any counter example to prove that this statement is false , according to me it should be correct , Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: Hint: Consider a diagonal matrix with the same element on all the diagonal entries.

Comment: The identity matrix has only one eigenvalue, however it admits linearly independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Every vector of a vector space $V$ is an eigenvector of the identity transformation (with eigenvalue $1$), so your conjecture is false.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.

Whenever a eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity $\gt 1$

Then , that eigenvalue has more than one linearly independent eigenvector.